# Can every logic ic output be connected directly to ground or Vcc in any case?

Tags: integrated-circuit, output, input

One day, someone here, I forgot who, wrote: "On modern ic's, every input and output pin can be connected directly to either ground or Vcc." Talking about ologic ic's.
Is it true? And is true all the time?

I read also many comments recommending not to do that and always add a resistor of several KOhms.
Adding a resistor protects the pin even when technically it's allowed to do so. But is adding a resistor at every pin permanently connected to ground or Vcc worth it? What would be the level of protection considering that neither ground or Vcc has a resistor? Advantages?

Connecting an output to a low impedance circuit to ground or directly to ground will make the pin transfer maximum current when it turns high. Can it be bad for the ic?
And similarly, can it be bad when an output is low while connected to a quasi-infinite source of current?

(This question does not qpply to open-drain pin, which de facto require a pull-up resistor.)

Comment: Let's just say it is not true all the time since EVERY input and output pin on EVERY IC is so broad so as to be completely useless. And why would you EVER connect an output of any kind (LM311 which has both open collector and emitter excepted)  directly to a power rail? And why would you ever connect a push pull output to a power rail through a resistor? Inputs to a power rail with or without pull ups is one matter, but outputs? Just...why?

Comment: This doesn’t sound right. If you connected the output of an op amp to ground you’d be drawing its short circuit current and possibly damage the device. Even if the device could handle it, it would waste power. So not very correct information.

Comment: @DKNguyen Connecting an output to a power rail or to ground doesn't make sens but it can happen, temporarily   when such connection is established. I know the question is very broad. The question is whether there is an universal construction nowadays allowing this on "almost" every ic's.

Comment: I narrowed the question to "logic ic's".

Comment: So you are referring not to intentional hardwired connections between out and rail, but incidental connections made during power sequencing?

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, intentionally or not, but obviously not premanently, As outputs are concerned. Maybe I should have divided this question for outputs and inputs. In fact the reason why the pin would be connected in such way is not part of the question. (It can be an experiment). The question is "what would happen if" (or could happen). If you will.

Comment: You should NEVER connect an IC OUTPUT directly to a power or ground rail.  For CMOS logic ICs, any unused INPUTS should be connected to power or ground so they will be held in known states. (For the pedantic, the output terminals of voltage regulators must be connected to the power rails they are intended to supply.)

Comment: @Peter Bennett If you could explain why in an answer, it would be great. Because my understanding is that outputs have limiting resistors to avoid shorts. Yet I agree, it would be a bad idea. But how bad is my question, Is it just wasting current or will it deteriorate the ic? About inputs, the question is can it be done without pull up or pull down resistor and directly to power or ground, when one need to keep a high or low state permanently.

Comment: It depends: a short term connection to a power or ground rail will cause excessive power dissipation in the the IC if the logic output is the opposite level.  You may get away with it if the duration is short enough.  A permanent connection never makes sense except via a resistor for impedance matching or pull up/down reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic inputs and outputs are different. Different families of logic IC (TTL, CMOS etc) behave differently. The manufacturers and commercial users anticipate things that hobby users don't usually. With almost every do/don't statement, there may be some exceptions that do not apply to hobby users.

1) Don't let CMOS inputs float, tie them to a logic level, another output, a rail either directly or through a pullup/pulldown resistor.

Why? CMOS inputs are high impedance, and are not expected to sit at a known logic level (like TTL does). Power consumption is vanishingly small when the input is at good logic level, and may be so high at mid rail that the IC overheats.

Why do people use a resistor to an input when that 'wastes' a component? Testing and modification. On board test programs are often generated automatically, and require every pin of every IC to be driveable when the board is put into a 'bed of nails' fixture. If you need to modify the function, then a presently unused pin is easier to use if it comes to a resistor terminal than if it's nailed to the ground plane under the IC. For both reasons, some commercial users have a rule that no IC pin ever goes directly to rail or ground.

2) Don't take any outputs to rail or ground. The resulting short circuit output current will almost surely eventually destroy the IC through heat or electromigration. If you're driving a load like a LED, ensure the maximum output current is within the continuous output current rating of the pin, which will be much lower than the short circuit current.

Why do ICs have any form of output current limiting and a short circuit current specification? Testing. When you're testing a board manually and you carelessly trail the ground clip of your 'scope probe across an output, even though it's your fault, if the board stops working, you're going to stop using that brand of impossible-to-work-with fragile IC. It's in the manufacturers interest to have their ICs survive brief foreseeable accidents.

When you're testing a board automatically, remember that we want every input to be driveable. Often inputs are connected directly to outputs. I used to work for a company that made board testers, and one of the most controversial methods of dealing with interconnected components was 'back driving', where the tester forced a node to a logic state to test the following IC, hopefully without destroying the IC driving that node.

3) Don't connect TTL inputs directly to rail.

Why? Most 5 V TTL families have an absolute maximum voltage of 7 V on the supply, but only 5.5 V on the inputs. It would be a shame to have an otherwise survivable 6.9 V surge across the power rail destroy ICs through lack of fault current limiting resistors on their inputs.

Comment: "When you're testing a board automatically, remember that we want every input to be driveable. Often inputs are connected directly to outputs. I used to work for a company that made board testers, and one of the most controversial methods of dealing with interconnected components was 'back driving', where the tester forced a node to a logic state to test the following IC, hopefully without destroying the IC driving that node." +1 That is good to know. I've only ever even attempted to do something like that with RS-422 lines board-to-board lines.

Comment: @DKNguyen The pin drivers could deliver up to +/-500 mA output current to do this foul deed, duration was only ever a few uS. There was always the question of whether it affected the long term reliability of the board, even if it did still work immediately afterwards.

Comment: "If you need to modify the function, then a presently unused pin is easier to use if it comes to a resistor terminal than if it's nailed to the ground plane under the IC" What kind of modification are you talking about? Are you referring to a post-reflow manual modification? Or something mass assembled?

Comment: @DKNguyen My industry was fairly niche in having mid volumes of mid price stuff, with very long development cycles. Often a function change would be needed, and we couldn't scrap the existing inventory, so were almost always selling equipment that contained hand-mods. They therefore needed to be tidy and robust, not the sort of thing you'd hack on your bench for a test.

Comment: In other words, your answer is "yes".

Comment: @DKNguyen the answer is no, outputs cannot be connected to ground. Or they can be, with bad consequences. They can be taken to ground, briefly, and should survive.

Comment: I was referring to my question: "Are you referring to a post-reflow manual modification? Or something mass assembled?"

Comment: I did myself two PCB's which required manual "post-reflow" reworking. I was very lucky I could solder two axial diodes from one hole to another. But still had to cut one trace with a graver. This is OK up to 100 pcs or so. After that better do another PCB. On another board I was also very lucky I used large 1.63 pin pitch (SOT) and not twice smaller (TTSOP) so I could solder wires to these pins. I wished I had a resistor to do these modifications. The latter was experimental only.

Comment: @Neil_UK As I understand TTL families better have a resistor between input and power but CMOS don't. Thank you very much for these explanations. They answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

Logic IC outputs do have resistance, but that resistance is generally not intended to limit output current to a safe value - it is just a byproduct of the transistors used in the output circuit.

The input circuits of CMOS logic ICs have a very high impedance.  If they are left unconnected, they will pick up random charges and assume random unkown values  In some cases, these random values may cause excessive currents in the IC, so unused inputs should be connected to a known logic level.

Comment: Yeah. Just because your transmission has friction doesnt mean you can omit the brakes!

Comment: I was expecting there to be mention that CMOS inputs can be tied directly to a rail with no resistor

Comment: Thanks for this answer, About the second part of the answer, is it necessary or highly recommended to add a resistor to ground or Vcc (depending of the logic you want) ?

Comment: "I was expecting there to be mention that CMOS inputs can be tied directly to a rail with no resistor" @DKNguyen Can they?

Comment: "unused inputs should be connected to a known logic level." - I think that implies that a CMOS input may be direclty connected to Power or Ground.

Comment: @Fredled For CMOS, yes. Resistors are required for BJT logic inputs like TTL for the same reason you need a series base resistor on a BJT..base-emitter junction is a diode not high impedance like the gate-source oxide layer (capacitor) of a MOSFET

Comment: @PeterBennett I guess I think it does not imply that since one can say "connect to a rail through a resistor"

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Texas Instruments datasheet of a high speed Cmos SN74HCxx logic IC. Its maximum allowed output current is 25mA. Then look at the graphs of output current vs output voltage and an output shorted to ground or to +VCC will produce a current of about 49mA and blow up the output transistor.
[image: HC logic output current]

Comment: But even these graphs or data in other datasheets, don't explain clearly what happens when you exceed current limit: Does the logic output become instable or its effect simply cancelled, or does it overheat and damage the ic... on top of cancelling the effect.

Comment: The 74HCxxx datasheet shows the absolute maximum allowed output current from one output is 25mA but only from no more than two outputs at the same time. The graph shows that it can produce enough output current to destroy the outputs of you do not properly limit the current.

Comment: How can it produce this current if it destroys the output? If the output is destroyed, it means it can't. And if it had been measured in order to draw this graph, it means it can, albeit at the absolute maximum limit. So it's not clear. It's not clear because they don;t explain whether the output becomes negative when more than 25mA is sunk or if it destroys the ic. The other answers above explains that. And the answer is both. But thanks anyway for your explanation.

Comment: Excessive current burns out the tiny Mosfets and wiring. Either they measured using a momentary pulse that was so brief that the parts did not overheat or they guessed what happens if the pulse current is too high.